# Angular binding to existence in array, or, performant computed properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, computed-properties

### The Problem

I'm wondering if there's a neat, performant way to bind an angular view to the *existence* of a particular item in an array. Basically, I have two controllers on one page. Controller A can delete or add items in an array that's injected by a service. I want Controller B, that's injected with the same service, to update its view when I do deletes or adds from Controller A.

### The Problem With Lobsters

Say I'm creating a lobster dating site. I'd have two views, side by side:

- **The hottest lobster view** shows a list of the hottest lobsters in the ocean. If any of these lobsters happens to be your friend, its list item will be highlighted and have a message saying that you're friends.
- **The lobster friends view** is on the same page as the hottest lobster view. If I unfriend a lobster from the lobster friend view, (i.e. remove the lobster from the `lobsterFriend` array), the hottest lobster view should update accordingly, and stop highlighting the unfriended lobster.

I'd like a solution that will work with large numbers of lobsters.

### The Setup

*Disclaimer: Code in this question is just for illustration purposes. I'm not actually creating a dating site for lobsters.*

I have an angular service that I'm injecting into two controllers. The service returns an array of objects.

**`lobsterFriendService`, a service for managing lobster friends:**

```
angular.module('lobsterDating')

.factory('lobsterFriendService', function($http) {
    return {
        // An array of lobsters
        lobsterFriends: $http.get('lobsterApi/lobsterFriends/'),

        addLobsterFriend: function (lobster) {
            this.lobsterFriends.push(lobster);
            $http.post('lobsterApi/lobsterFriends/', lobster);
        },

        deleteLobsterFriend: function (crustaceanId) {
            this.lobsterFriends = this.lobsterFriends.filter(function (lobster) { return lobster.id !== crustaceanId; });
            $http.delete('lobsterApi/lobsterFriends/', crustaceanId);
        }
    }
});
```

---

**`LobsterFriendsCtrl`, a controller for the friends list, injected with `lobsterFriendService`:**

```
angular.module('lobsterDating')

.controller('LobsterFriendsCtrl', ["lobsterFriendService", function(lobsterFriendService) {

    $scope.removeFriend = function (lobsterId) {
        lobsterFriendService.deleteLobsterFriend(lobsterId);
    }

}]);
```

---

**`HottestLobsterCtrl`, a controller for the hottest lobster page:**

```
angular.module('lobsterDating')

.controller('HottestLobstersCtrl', ["lobsterFriendService", "hottestLobsters" function(lobsterFriendService, hottestLobsters) {
    $scope.model = {
        hottestLobsters: hottestLobsters
    };

    $scope.lobsterIsFriend = function (lobsterId) {
        return lobsterFriendService.lobsterFriends.contains(lobsterId);
    }

    $scope.addLobsterFriend = function (lobster) {
        lobsterFriendService.addLobsterFriend(lobster);
    }

}]);
```

---

**`hottestLobsters.html`, the view bound to `HottestLobsterCtrl`:**

```
<div ng-repeat="lobster in model.hottestLobsters">
    <div class="lobsterFriend" ng-if="lobsterIsFriend(lobster.id)">{{lobster.name}} is your friend ;)</div>
    <div class="twoClawsUp" ng-if="lobsterIsFriend(lobster.id)" ng-click="addLobsterFriend(lobster)">Two claws up for {{lobster.name}}!</div>
</div>
```

### Possible Solutions

1. Set up a watch on the `lobsterFriends` array. When it updates, we can update some property on the `HottestLobsterCtrl` controller, trigger a digest, etc. I think this would be rather expensive.
2. Emit an event whenever a lobster is friended or unfriended. This is a path I'd want to avoid going down if possible, as I'm already injecting a service with the actual object right there.
3. Use some sort of helper library that handles computed properties nicely.
4. ???? Please help?

Comment: I see you had fun writing this question.  The question was well structured however I found it abit lengthy and somewhat offpoint.  Can I clarify what you're really trying to ask is how two independent controllers can talk to each other and update each others view?

Comment: The problem isn't so much how to get two controllers to talk to each other- that's easily solved by the existing service. I want to bind to the _existence_ of a particular object in an array returned by the service.

For example, if I have Steve as a friend, I'd like to have his corresponding profile in another view to be highlighted, or have a friend icon, etc. But I'd also like Steve's profile to change when I delete him from my friends list in another controller. I'll edit the post to make this clearer.

Comment: Sorry not getting it.  Do you want to do something in Controller A which changes data in the service and at the same time let Controller B know about it? i.e when data in the service changes, both controller need to know?

Comment: I just updated the question. Say I have a view with a list of lobsters, and one of them happens to be my friend. I'd like to display friended lobsters differently. I check if a given lobster is a friend by checking if their id exists in the `lobsterFriends` array. My question is, how would I bind to whether an object/id exists in an array (in a performant way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is save the data in a single obj/array and when you update, simply change the value of that object and array instead of keeping two arrays.  You can think of this as a master array.  The reason for this is because obj/array gets passed by reference thus it doesn't matter which controller they are in, it will be the same data.  [Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ajGMwYMqPhzLngL7hJEY?p=preview)

```
service('dataHolder', function(){
  this.data = [{
    name : 'Joe',
    isFriend: false
  },
  {
    name : 'Michelle',
    isFriend: false
  },
  {
    name : 'Adam',
    isFriend: true
  },
  {
    name : 'West',
    isFriend: false
  }] 
})
```

In your example, if you find a way to combine hottestLobsters and LobsterFriends in a single object through a merge and control them through properties then there is no need to have any watch or broadcast .  It will simply be like sharing the same scope.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I updated the plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gu1UJ89O7XFnJtxkS97F?p=preview). The hottest friends view has data that changes dynamically, which is my problem. How would I go about mapping the `isFriend` property every time either the `hottestPeople` array changes, or a friend is added or deleted?

Comment: I've updated the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/7g6KtMBfuQGM41wNzyvX?p=preview to fit your needs.  The main point here is that angular services are all singletons, hence you can load all your data into a data manager service and change it in there to reflect all the views.  The best way is to have a master obj which has property information about friends list and hottest list.  However, if you wish to have more than 1 obj, you'll just have to load them in the same service and then manipulate them when something changes.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of putting the data from the hottest people controller back onto the service, that will work nicely!